# iOS 11/12 Core Audio - Crackling / Popping Audio

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

#### My configuration

iPhone X

iOS 12

#### Problem

Since iOS 11/12 my apps audio for some reason has a periodic crackling/popping sound which appears to get worse/more noticeable the louder or more constant the audio is.

#### Troubleshooting

I played a 800Hz sine wave from djay2 through AudioBus into my app and saved the output of my app to a file.

Loading my apps output into Audacity I can see that the crackling occurs every 14,112 samples or every 0.320 seconds.

Has anyone got any idea where I should start looking. Changing the internal configuration of my app between 41.1kHz and 48kHz appears to make no difference. I thought it might have been due to downsampling from the hardware sample rate.

[image: Waveform One]

[image: Waveform Two]

[image: Waveform Three]

Toggling *Inter-App Audio Sync* on/off within AudioBus appears to have some effect (1 in every ~8 toggles will stop the crackling).

I assume this is due to the AudioSession being restarted or something.

Has anyone got any idea what might be causing this or has experienced this before?

Thanks,

Anthony

Comment: getting same issue on different phone with same OS ?  write a simple toy audio app using same software stack - does it also have same issue ? what does phone system log say ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ScottStensland. I have customers reporting the issue on iPhone 8 devices running iOS 12. I created a test app today with only my audio engine, no other logic or even a UI and it exhibits the exact same problem. Nothing in the system console that relates to audio.

Comment: I know the frustration of Apple shipping buggy code ... I once had to re-write from scratch the http live streaming ( HLS ) software stack which replaced Apple's buggy firmware ... here is other folks with same issue  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8370078

Comment: possibly try this https://discussions.apple.com/message/33945249#message33945249

Comment: did you solve it?